# Using multiple web pages in a web scraper

Tags: python, social-media

I've been working on some Python code to be able to get links to social media accounts from government websites, for a research into ease with which municipalities can be contacted. I've managed to adapt some code to work in 2.7, which prints all links to facebook, twitter, linkedin and google+ present on a given input website. The issue I'm currently experiencing is that I'm not looking for links on just the one web page, but on a list of about 200 websites, I have in an Excel file. I have no experience with importing these sorts of lists into Python, so I was wondering if anybody could take a look at the code, and suggest a proper way to set all these web pages as the base_url, if possible;

```
import cookielib

import mechanize

base_url = "http://www.amsterdam.nl"

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent',
              'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
page = br.open(base_url, timeout=10)

links = {}
for link in br.links():
    if link.url.find('facebook')>=0 or link.url.find('twitter')>=0 or link.url.find('linkedin')>=0 or link.url.find('plus.google')>=0:
    links[link.url] = {'count': 1, 'texts': [link.text]}

# printing
for link, data in links.iteritems():
print "%s - %s - %s - %d" % (base_url, link, ",".join(data['texts']), data['count'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned that you have a excel file with the list of all the websites right ? Therefore you can export the excel file as a `csv` file which you can then read values from in your python code.

[Here's some more information regarding that](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter14/).

[Here's how to work directly with excel files](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/)

You can do something along the lines :

```
import csv

links = []

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # Simple example where only a single column of URL's is present
    links = list(csv_reader)
```

Now `links` is a list of all the URLs. You can then loop over the list inside a function which fetches the page and scrapes the data.

```
def extract_social_links(links):
    for link in links:
        base_url = link 

        br = mechanize.Browser()
        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        br.set_cookiejar(cj)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.set_handle_equiv(False)
        br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),     max_time=1)
        br.addheaders = [('User-agent',
          'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
        page = br.open(base_url, timeout=10)

        links = {}
        for link in br.links():
            if link.url.find('facebook')>=0 or link.url.find('twitter')>=0 or     link.url.find('linkedin')>=0 or link.url.find('plus.google')>=0:
            links[link.url] = {'count': 1, 'texts': [link.text]}

        # printing
        for link, data in links.iteritems():
        print "%s - %s - %s - %d" % (base_url, link, ",".join(data['texts']), data['count'])
```

As an aside, you should probably split your if conditions to make them more readable.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, to just add all links to a list, thanks. One error I've encountered with your code is given;

 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\Research Project GRS 50806\Preexisting data\Test - kopie.py", line 11, in <module>
    data.links(list(csv_reader))
    NameError: name 'data' is not defined`


Is there any way to define data as a valid syntax?

Comment: @StefanFörch my bad, when I edited the answer I did not edit all instances of the list `links`. I'm editing it now. That line there is to add the list of links to the empty list we previously defined to be used later.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much, the code that adds the items from the CSV-file to a list seems to be working, since `print lists` gives `[['http://www.amsterdam.nl/', ' http://www.rotterdam.nl/', ' http://www.denhaag.nl/', ' http://www.utrecht.nl']]`. However, when using the entire code, it just doesn't seem to run. I'm assuming this might have something to do with the link format, however, I don't see how the document should be formatted, e.g. should quotation marks be used, should it be a list with values in a single column, etc?

Comment: @StefanFörch did you call the function with the list of links ? If so then try printing the url which is being crawled in the particular iteration of the loop by adding a `print link` after the for loop invocation.

Comment: What I've done is described in the code given here; https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8ad503f32f282cc3489
 
The error given is `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: Judging by your previous comment, I think you need to change `for link in links:` to `for link in links[0]:` and try again.

Comment: Or you can change the line `links.extend(list(csv_reader))` to `links = list(csv_reader)`

Comment: I've changed `for link in links:` to `for link in links[0]`, and changing the number in the brackets allows me to check one specific webpage in the csv file. Would there also be a code which would allow me to check all webpages at once, or at least, without having to change the code in between?

Comment: Have a look at this https://gist.github.com/bIgBV/30ec444f5d7cf45bc616 , the thing is, make sure that the list `links` actually contains all the links in itself, instead of it being nested list `[['url1', 'url2'....` . What you need to pass to the function `extract_social_links` is a list of links, not a list of a list of links.